# page fault,shortage of page or access violation?

Tags: exception, operating-system, x86, kernel

It is known that when access a page which does not exist in the memory can lead to a page fault, but writing a read-only page can also cause a page fault? How to identify the two types of page fault in exception handler?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You read the exception error code that the CPU places on the stack before invoking your page fault handler. This error code contains 5 bits, of which you're interested in these 4:

- P=0: The fault was caused by a non-present page.
  P=1: The fault was caused by a page-level protection violation.
- W/R=0: The access causing the fault was a read.
  W/R=1: The access causing the fault was a write.
- U/S=0: The access causing the fault originated when the processor
  was executing in supervisor mode.
  U/S=1: The access causing the fault originated when the processor
  was executing in user mode.
- I/D=0: The fault was not caused by an instruction fetch.
  I/D=1: The fault was caused by an instruction fetch.

If you get P=0, the page isn't present.

If you get P=1, the privileges are insufficient to access the page. U/S tells you if it's in the kernel or application. I/D tells you if it's because of code instruction reading or not (reading/writing data). W/R tells you if it is reading or writing that can't be done.

This is described in the `Interrupt 14—Page-Fault Exception (#PF)` section of the `Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer’s Manual, Volume 3: System Programming Guide`.

Answer (score 2):

Alex's answer is perfectly correct, however you also need to combine that information with some information of your own (i.e. by looking at the memory manager data). For example some operating systems don't allocate pages backing memory until they're referenced for the first time, so if you get a read or a write to a page which is not present you may find that the reason it is not present is that you haven't allocated it yet and you should allocate it and continue from the exception. Similarly a write to a read only page can occur as part of a copy-on-write mechanism (a number of systems do this, most notably posix style systems when performing fork()), so you detect the write to a read only page, check the memory manager tables and see the page should be copied, copy the page, update the page tables and continue.

I've found that usually the only flag from the list Alex mentions that is interesting is the one that says whether it was a read or a write. Beyond that you need to check everything else from the MM tables anyway.

Answer (score -2):

Trying to write to read only will usually cause a segmentation fault (SIGSEGV).

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault

I think its called an access violation exception (memory access violation) in x86 parlance.

Comment: At the CPU level these are all page faults (#PF exception). When the OS gets the page fault it works out what happened by looking at the MM database and generates one of the exceptions you mention. Access Violation is Windows terminology for what unix calls SIGSEGV. There is nothing specifically x86 about it.